# nav with display: inline-block not centering in css?

Tags: css, block, center, inline

I am trying to center my nav with display:inline-block in css?

```
nav {
position: fixed;
width: 100%;
}

nav ul {
width: 100%;
margin: auto;
}

nav ul li {
display: inline-block; 
margin: 5px 20px 5px 20px;
text-align: center; 
}
```

Comment: text-align for inline-boxes has to be set on parent in order to see them in the middle :=

Comment: You need commas after each element you want to style: Example: `nav, ul, li, a {
text-decoration: none;
}` Hopefully that was what was wrong. Hope this helps! @user3606785

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simply add `text-align:center;` to the parent element of the `inline-block` element.

```
nav {
position: fixed;
width: 100%;
}

nav ul {
width: 100%;
margin: auto;
text-align:center;
}

nav ul li {
display: inline-block; 
margin: 5px 20px 5px 20px;
text-align: center; 
}
```